# knowing $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \log x = +\infty$ prove $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x^{-\alpha} = 0$ for $\alpha > 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

We know that

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} {x^{-\alpha}} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-\alpha \log x}$$

If I can do the substitution $t = \alpha \log x$, then the proof is trivial. Namely, we know that $t \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$ and we also know that $\lim_{t \to +\infty} e^{-t} = 0$, which would conclude the proof.

Can I do that substitution? Is there anything I should keep in mind when doing similar replacements of variables in limits?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems fine to me

Comment: @RamanujanXXV Thanks! Do you know of any theorem that would justify such a substitution?

Comment: Your explanation is fine. When $x\to \infty $ then $t\to\infty. $ That's all you need.